# ReactNative - Cant get my const to update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

im trying to modify my const value using `onChangeText`, but it keeps returning "undefined".

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, KeyboardAvoidingView, Image, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, alert, Alert } from 'react-native';


export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(' ');

  login = (user) => {
    Alert.alert("Bem vindo, " + user, "Login realizado!")
  }

  return (
    
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.background}>
      <View style={styles.containerLogo}>
        <Image
        source={require('./src/logo.png')}
        style= {{width: 300, height: 300}}
        />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Usuário"
        autoCorrect={false}
        onChangeText = {(user) => setUser(user)}
        />

        <TextInput 
        style={styles.input}
        secureTextEntry={true}
        placeholder="Senha"
        autoCorrect={false}
        onChangeText={()=>{}}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity 
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={ () => {login()}}
          >
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
          Entrar
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>

    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
   
  );
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

It is undefined because `login` is defined to take a `user` argument. You don't pass it any value in the callback so the local function variable `user` is undefined.

## Solution

You need to pass `user` to the `login` function.

```
login = user => {
  Alert.alert("Bem vindo, " + user, "Login realizado!") // <-- local scope user
}

...

onPress={() => login(user)} // <-- user state object
```

Or let `login` simply consume the `user` state that is in functional component body scope.

```
login = () => {
  Alert.alert("Bem vindo, " + user, "Login realizado!") // <-- user state object
}

...

onPress={login}
```